# Skip to index in for-in loop

Tags: swift, swift4

Let's say I have a for-in loop like this:

```
for index in 1...5 {

}
```

And let's say that I find that, at index 2, I want to skip to index 4 due to some condition. The following does not work:

```
for index in 1...5 {
    if index == 2 {
        index = 4
    }
}
```

Because it gives me the following error:

> Cannot assign to value: 'index' is a 'let' constant

How can I modify the position of the index to skip to index 4?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? It might be better to use a `while` loop instead, or to produce a custom sequence to iterate with a `for` loop instead of just `1...5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a for loop, you cannot jump the index in real time - that is, if you discover once the loop has started that you need to skip an iteration, you can't. But you can duck out of an iteration with `continue`. So for example:

```
var skip = 0
for i in 1...5 {
    if i < skip { continue }
    print(i)
    if i == 2 { skip = 4}
}
```

In a situation like this, however, you might be happier with a while loop.

```
var i = 1
while i <= 5 {
    print(i)
    i += 1
    if i == 3 { i = 4 }
}
```

Another possibility is to unroll the original for loop into a while loop:

```
var r = (1...5).makeIterator()
while let i = r.next() {
    print(i)
    if i == 2 { r.next() }
}
```

All of those are ways of printing `1,2,4,5`.